# How should one analyze the video of the Antares CRS-3 explosion to find the clues to the cause?

Tags: launch, failure, antares, rocket-explosion

From the raw video of the event (which just happened), a trained eye can narrow the possibilities, given good general knowledge of the rocket. What in the video indicates which systems were involved, what kind of failure occurred, and how the failure progressed?

I know that proper analysis will follow, but what should one look at in the video as definite information as to the nature of this event?

Edit: Here is the video released by [NASA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQQoKTuVScM)

And a [second angle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4SH1B7tzJY&src_vid=A4sahTq42mk&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_748814267) including a fair bit of close-up footage, although it misses some key seconds. (It is a large group of reporters filming from nearby, and members of the public, and includes a lot of personal reactions).

Comment: I'm not particularly trained, but it looks like there's a brief flash at the base of the rocket prior to the larger fireball. I'd guess one of the two rocket engines failed catastrophically, and that relatively small explosion ruptured the fuel tanks, releasing a lot of kerosene and LOX. I don't know if you're looking for a more detailed guess than that :)

Comment: Well, preferably information that can be said for sure, or things that can definitely be ruled out. For instance, i take it it was too far down to have started in a fuel tank. But maybe it could have been a fuel line *or* an engine?

Comment: Fuel tanks themselves don't usually have catastrophic problems. A ruptured fuel line would probably lead to an engine shutdown -- I don't know about Antares specifically, but rockets are usually set up to shut down the engines quickly when things go wrong, so you don't continue powered flight in an uncontrollable direction.

Comment: Watching it live, it seemed like there was a small explosion at around t+3 seconds. The rocket started to descend (though it was difficult to see) before finally hitting the ground and exploding in a fireball. My guess is that there was an issue in the lower half of the rocket (which is where it seemed the initial explosion occurred) which led to engine failure, and then the large explosion.

Comment: An explosion near the bottom. You can clearly see most of the rocket is intact after the initial event.

Comment: So it sounds like it can be narrowed to engine failure. But not all kinds of engine failures would cause and explosion, would they? Something had to rupture  due to structural failure and/or excess pressure? And the rocket took a while to fall, for some reason that can be deduced from this?

Comment: Well, it was moving upward relatively fast, so, unless the explosion pushed it downwards, it would travel upwards for a bit and then sink down.

Comment: Is stackexchange really the place to speculate about this?  This question and any answers based on just a video will have no long-term value, since what happened will be resolved with far more data and a report will be issued.

Comment: While it is exciting to talk about now, until we hear answers from NASA and Orbital Sciences this is ends up as a rather speculative question, and for the moment it should be closed or put on hold. Wait for the proper analysis and then we can determine how they relate to what we saw in the video.

Comment: I would suggest emphasizing the part about _"what should one look at"_ and rewriting the title to reflect that. If the question focused on that, then I'd say it's fine and not speculative at all. But the title still suggests it's asking us to draw conclusions based on limited data we have available (basically video of it from a few angles, launch timeline and some of the flight profile that was shared to the public). Perhaps asking more directly about flight anomaly investigation techniques and the role of video footage in it wouldn't go amiss either.

Comment: The N-1 strikes back from the grave.

Comment: I appreciate the help making this question up to standard.

Answer (score 5):

I'll just start with some things that came to my mind. Not planning to provide a complete list here.

You can look at the craft itself prior to and shortly after launch. Was there any leakage or jets of propellant where there shouldn't be any? For example, smoke was visible during the final launch of the space shuttle Challenger.

Comparing the video to a [previous launch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYYNc2_EqQY) we find no obvious leakage. However, the night launch makes it difficult to see much of the vehicle at all.

The next thing that came to my mind was the guidance system failing and causing automatic self-destruction, a bit like on that recent Proton launch. The rocket does sway to the side a bit after launch, but that may be on purpose, in order not to recontact the launch tower. It does the same in the other video.

Now, I'm going out on limb and speculate a bit from the poor footage available. The flame in of the exhaust turns from yellow-blue to bright yellow a split second before the explosion. One explanation (not the only explanation) for this would be a failure in the oxygen supply, so the rocket quickly goes to extremely fuel-rich combustion.

However the oxygen pump of the [NK-33](http://lpre.de/resources/articles/AIAA-1998-3361.pdf) is on the same shaft as the fuel pump, and located between the turbine and the fuel pump. So the fuel pump can't keep working when the oxygen pump has stopped (or exploded).

Now it would be interesting to have a high-res video from another perspective to see if both engines fail simultaneously. If they do, my oracle is this: There was loss of pressure on the oxygen tank or an obstruction in the ducts. This caused the combustion to go extremely fuel rich for a split second, until the dry-running turbo-pump bearings (which must be cooled with liquid oxygen) overheated. This ignited the metal of the pump housing, leading to the rest of all this unpleasantness.

Comment: Reports are that the self destruct was not automatic; a signal was sent by the launch range safety officer.

Comment: [This article says NASA concluded it was likely a turbopump failure on the AJ-26](http://www.spaceflightinsider.com/missions/commercial/nasa-details-orbital-sciences-will-need-complete-crs-contract/).